# Postgresql custom sort function

Tags: postgresql

I want to select the maximum values for sorting purposes in a database defined along these lines,

```
cars_sold INTEGER,
tires_sold INTEGER,
batteries_sold INTEGER,
```

and I would like to sort and return the top total_sold based on something like this,

```
total_sold = (cars_sold * 100) + (tires_sold * 10) + (batteries_sold * 2)
```

Is there an aggregate function for something like this or do I need to write my own function?
Also, is the cost going to be ridiculous for a function like that?
Thanks,

Comment: All the basic information is missing. Postgres version, table definition, sample data, proper description of desired result. What have you tried? Please improve your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Erwin is right, you should really always include your Postgresql version and as much schema information as you can, but...at least on Postgresql 9.3, the following will work:

```
 create temp table foo(cars_sold int, tires_sold int, batteries_sold int);
 insert into foo values (1, 2, 3);
 insert into foo values (2, 3, 4);
 insert into foo values (10, 3, 4);
 insert into foo values (0, 6, 7);

 select *, (cars_sold * 100) + (tires_sold * 10) + (batteries_sold * 2) as total_sold 
 from foo 
 order by total_sold;
```